# WPF Run CMD line with simple argument, print output - without batch file

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, cmd

I'm having some difficulty doing this without using a batch file. What I want to do is when a button is clicked, run the command line with a simple argument that I specify.

Here's my code so far:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;        
startInfo.Arguments = "dir";
Process.Start(startInfo);
string output = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
txtblkOutput.Text = output;
```

However, this just opens a cmd window and nothing happens. The text box remains blank.

However I can do this:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Users/user/Documents/SUB-20 Tool/commands.bat";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
txtblkOutput.Text = output;
```

Inside the batch file it just says `dir`. And this works, I get the output sent to my textbox.

Why does this work only with a batch file? Can I do this without it, with just using the argument property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the excepted behaviour. When you execute `cmd.exe` with the argument `dir`, it does not execute the command.

As an exemple, see the screenshot below :
[image]

[The correct way](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to execute a command in the arguments is the following :

```
cmd.exe /C <command>
```

Comment: This would be FileName contents, correct? (process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe /C dir";)   If i do that, i get an error that the system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I split up the command into Filename and Arguments. I used "cmd.exe" for Filename property, and "/C dir" for Arguments property. This worked!

Comment: @hereiam That is what I was thinking about. I should have been more explicit.